# Can't copy image file with larg size in flash memory

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-xp-sp3

I want copy image file with large size(4G) to flash memory in Windows XP os and capacity of flash memory is 8G and free, but windows shows error dialog : "The disk in the destination drive is full".

Comment: This should be on http://superuser.com

Comment: Format the flash drive with a filesystem that supports large files.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for your response. I do formated flash but don't correct.

Comment: Formta with Fat32 on windows.

Comment: I found my answer myself ;). In Fat32 file format maximum file size is 4G so I formatting flash memory with NTFS file format and problem fixed.

Comment: well, David Schwartz found the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAT32 file system supports drives larger than 4GB, but individual files cannot be larger than 4GB-1 (4294967295) bytes. If you must store such large files you will need to use a different file system. The most commonly used file system which supports such large files is NTFS.